# How to show a popup when I click on a marker openlayers

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core, openlayers

I have made some markers on my map, each marker represents a report sent from that location.
I want to do that when I click on a specific marker I'll have its information on a popup.
The info is stored in a SQL database and it contains `Category`, `Title`, `Remarks`(Description), `statUrgence`(Urgence) & `images Path`(path). You can see it in the code as `@_Data.Category` ...

Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/ol.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/ol-ext.css">

<script src="~/js/ol.js"></script>


<div id="map" style="position: fixed; top: 62.5px; left: 0; bottom: 65px; right: 0; z-index:-1"></div>

<style>
    .ol-zoom {
        top: 2.5%;
    }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var layers = [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() })];

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            zoom: 5,
            center: [166326, 5992663]
        }),
        interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate: false, pinchRotate: false }),
        layers: layers
    });

    const options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    //Tried to make here that when a marker is clicked something will happen, wasn't much of a success 
    // Vector Feature Popup logic
    map.on('click', function (e) {
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
            console.log(feature, layer);
        })
    })


</script>

@{


    if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var _Data in Model)
        {
            @*Saving the data that needs to be in each marker*@
            @*<div class="card" id="overlay-container-@_Data.Id" style="display:none;">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3><u>Category</u>: @_Data.category</h3><br />
                    <h5><u>Title</u>: @_Data.title</h5>
                </div><br />
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>
                        <u>Description</u>: <br />@_Data.remarks
                    </p><br />
                    <u>Urgence</u>: @_Data.statUrgence <br />
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    @_Data.path
                </div>
            </div>*@

            <script>
                markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
                    style: new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Icon({
                            anchor: [0.5, 1],
                            src: 'https://ucarecdn.com/4b516de9-d43d-4b75-9f0f-ab0916bd85eb/marker.png'
                        })
                    })
                });

                 map.addLayer(markers);

                var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([parseFloat(@_Data.coordLat), parseFloat(@_Data.coordLong)]));
                markers.getSource().addFeature(marker);

            </script>
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am sorry if the question wasn't clear, 
the question is, How do I make custom popup screen to each of those markers (and display the correct data to each one of those popups)

Comment: Still remains: what have you tried, what did you expect etc. How to ask

Answer (score 2):

Include the properties you need in the popup as properties of the features, then you can copy them to the popup as required, as with `name` in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html  Complex popups can be created and styled as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html

End result of that using a simple subset of your properties and no extra css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Popup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.1.0/ol/ol.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.1.0/ol/dist/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
       html, body, .map {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
       }

      .ol-popup {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
        filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        bottom: 12px;
        left: -50px;
        min-width: 280px;
      }
      .ol-popup:after, .ol-popup:before {
        top: 100%;
        border: solid transparent;
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
      }
      .ol-popup:after {
        border-top-color: white;
        border-width: 10px;
        left: 48px;
        margin-left: -10px;
      }
      .ol-popup:before {
        border-top-color: #cccccc;
        border-width: 11px;
        left: 48px;
        margin-left: -11px;
      }
      .ol-popup-closer {
        text-decoration: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        right: 8px;
      }
      .ol-popup-closer:after {
        content: "✖";
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
      <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
      <div id="popup-content"></div>
    </div>
    <script>

      /**
       * Elements that make up the popup.
       */
      const container = document.getElementById('popup');
      const content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
      const closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

      /**
       * Create an overlay to anchor the popup to the map.
       */
      const overlay = new ol.Overlay({
        element: container,
        autoPan: {
          animation: {
            duration: 250,
          },
        },
      });

      /**
       * Add a click handler to hide the popup.
       * @return {boolean} Don't follow the href.
       */
      closer.onclick = function() {
        overlay.setPosition(undefined);
        closer.blur();
        return false;
      };

      const Model = [
        {
          category: 'Capital city',
          title: 'London',
          long: -0.12755,
          lat: 51.507222,
          description: 'UK capital',
        },
        {
          category: 'Capital city',
          title: 'Rome',
          long: 12.5,
          lat: 41.9,
          description: 'Italy capital',
        },
        {
          category: 'Capital city',
          title: 'Bern',
          long: 7.4458,
          lat: 46.95,
          description: 'Switzerland capital',
        },
      ];


      /**
       * Create the map.
       */
      const map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
          }),
        ],
        overlays: [overlay],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([7.5, 47]),
          zoom: 3,
        }),
      });

      const features = [];
      for (key in Model)
      {
        const _Data = Model[key];
        const feature = new ol.Feature({
          geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
            ol.proj.fromLonLat([parseFloat(_Data.long), parseFloat(_Data.lat)])
          ),
          category: _Data.category,
          title: _Data.title,
          description: _Data.description,
        });
        features.push(feature);
      }

      const markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          features: features,
        }),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Icon({
            anchor: [0.5, 1],
            src: 'https://ucarecdn.com/4b516de9-d43d-4b75-9f0f-ab0916bd85eb/marker.png',
          }),
        }),
      });

      map.addLayer(markers);  

      map.on('click', function (evt) {
        const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature) {
          return feature;
        });
        if (feature) {
          const coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
          content.innerHTML =
            '<p>Category:</p><code>' + feature.get('category') + '</code><br>' +
            '<p>Title:</p><code>' + feature.get('title') + '</code><br>' +
            '<p>Description:</p><code>' + feature.get('description') + '</code>'
          overlay.setPosition(coordinates);
        }
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```